# How to write comments in mac configuration files

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, osx-mavericks

I'm just curious if there is a convention or proper way to add comments to the configuration files in the Mac OS (10.9.4 or above) such that it will not affect whatever reads the file.

For example I just read on another post what `~/.CFUserTextEncoding` is used for and how to configure it. In a few days time I'm going to forget where I found this useful information and I would like to keep it in the one place I know I will find it again, in the file itself.

Is there a way I can add this useful information to the file without messing with the OS parsing it?

Comment: Since different parsers can make anything a token to delimit comments or code or whatever, I don't believe there is a uniform way. You are however free to create companion files (i.e. ~/.CFUserTextEncoding.meta) that contain whatever further information you think might be useful.

Comment: Thanks! That is a reasonable idea, since there is no way of easily knowing what delimiters OSX uses for a given file. I was just hoping that there might be some convention I didn't know about that I could use.